# PHP cli_set_process_title had an error: Not initialized correctly on Mac OSX

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a different process title for every fork in PHP CLI on Mac OSX version 5.5.11, but

```
 cli_set_process_title(): 
     cli_set_process_title had an error: Not initialized correctly
```

The PHP Manual [cli_set_process_title](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cli-set-process-title.php) entry has not special things to take care.

I try with

```
 setproctitle()
```

but doesn't works fine, the proc title is: the title, many blank spaces and my $PATH partially... as explains a recomendation in the PHP manual for [setproctitle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setproctitle.php):

> You should use cli_set_process_title() (
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.cli-set-process-title.php ) instead;
>   it's less dangerous and less buggy, and part of PHP itself as of 5.5.

Any suggestion are welcome!

Comment: PHP 5.5.11 (cli) (built: May 30 2014 18:13:30) + OSX: works like charm

Comment: An E_WARNING will be generated if the operating system is unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem and it looks like it was a permission issue in my case.

Solved running the command with `sudo`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by adding `@ before cli_set_process_title.`

It's the error suppression operator, the last resort. Normally not a good idea to use it as you should be trapping errors cleanly rather than simply hiding them.

But in my case whole script works.